# Error (Xcode):Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary /ios/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not contain Running lipo-info:

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tried the all solution of google. But this issue not fixes at the time of building and releasing iOS app. Please gave some suggestion on this,

This is my flutter doctor -verbose

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.7.6 on channel stable at /Users/ftbcolab/.flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12cb4eb7a0 (7 days ago), 2023-03-01 10:29:26 -0800
    • Engine revision ada363ee93
    • Dart version 2.19.3
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ftbcolab/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/ftbcolab/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.177
    ! Error: Sumedh’s iPhone is busy: Waiting to connect and unlock the device. Xcode will continue when Sumedh’s iPhone is finished. (code -10)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I tried the all solution of google. But this issue not fixes at the time of building and releasing iOS app. Please gave some suggestion on this,How to fix this problem and make the release of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete these lines in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

```
EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64;
"EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = arm64;
```